# How to stream an encrypted file?

Tags: java, encryption, jersey, video-streaming

I want to stream an encrypted file from the back-end to the front end using a jersey rest API. I searched on the internet for some clues. I found something that i thought could get the job done: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2467. There is an example on how to random access an cipherinputstream. I can stream the video, but i can't search through the video with the standard html5 videoplayer slider.

The problem is i don't know how to get the offset from the videoplayer where the video needs to continue playing.

Below is my endpoint. The StreamingCipherInputStream is the same as in the link above.

```
`@GET
 @Produces("video/mp4")
 @Path("stream/{id}")
 public Response streamVideo(@PathParam("id") int id) throws Exception {
     Video video = videoservice.getVideo(id);
     StreamingCipherInputStream in = 
     videoservice.getVideoInputStream(video.getFilename());
     StreamingOutput entity = output -> {
         ReaderWriter.writeTo(in, output);
     };
     return Response.ok(entity).build();
 }`
```

My question is how can i make it work with everything i have or are the some better options i'm missing?